# SQL Server return JSON array of ids for rows that match

Tags: json, sql-server

I want to be able to return a JSON array of ids as part of a JSON object from SQL Server.

I have tried to get this to work and have come close but it is not the way I want the JSON to be structered.

This SQL I have outputs this

```
SELECT c.Pk_Company_Id AS [id],
       c.Name AS [name],
       r.Pk_Rig_Id AS [rigId]
FROM Company c
LEFT JOIN Rig r
ON c.Pk_Company_Id = r.Fk_Company_Id
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('companies')

{"companies":[{"id":1,"name":"Company 1","rigId":100},{"id":1,"name":"Company 1","rigId":101},{"id":2,"name":"Company 2"}]}
```

This produces JSON that has everything I want kind of but I would like to structure rigIds as a JSON Array to produce something like this so i am not duplicating an object for no reason.

```
{"companies":[{"id":1,"name":"Company 1","rigIds":[100, 101]},{"id":2,"name":"Company 2"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant with `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
  c.Pk_Company_Id AS [id],
  c.Name AS [name],
  JSON_QUERY(REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT r.Pk_Rig_Id id FROM Rig r WHERE c.Pk_Company_Id = r.Fk_Company_Id FOR JSON PATH),'{"id":',''),'}','')) [rigIds]
FROM Company c
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('companies')

-- {"companies":[{"id":1,"name":"Company 1","rigIds":[100,101]},{"id":2,"name":"Company 2"}]}
```

A variant with `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT
  c.Pk_Company_Id AS [id],
  c.Name AS [name],
  JSON_QUERY((SELECT '['+STRING_AGG(r.Pk_Rig_Id,',')+']' FROM Rig r WHERE c.Pk_Company_Id = r.Fk_Company_Id)) [rigIds]
FROM Company c
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('companies')
```

Comment: Thank you, both work! I like the STRING_AGG solution.

Comment: Good luck! I also like the solution with `STRING_AGG` better. ))